# ModelForm not showing up in Django template?

Tags: django, models, django-forms

## models

```
class VideoInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    video_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cameraman = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    editor = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    reporter = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tag = models.TextField()
```

## forms

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput())


class VideoInfoForm(forms.Form):

     class Meta:
         model = VideoInfo
         fields = ['video_type', 'director', 'cameraman', 'editor', 'reporter', 'tag']
```

## Views:

```
class Main(View):
    '''Index page of application'''
    def get(self, request):
        model = VideoInfo
        form = VideoInfoForm()
        return render_to_response('main.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Calling in template as:

```
{{form.as_p}}
```

The form is not showing up but if I use `LoginForm` it's showing up. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to inherit second form from ModelForm, please read the docs carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
class VideoInfoForm(forms.Form):
```

To:

```
class VideoInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to use model form, your definition of the form is not correct.

Change

```
class VideoInfoForm(forms.Form):
```

to

```
class VideoInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
#       ------------------^ use ModelForm not Form
```

Sidenote:

Instead of long list of `fields` use `exclude` to just list fields that are not needed.

```
class VideoInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = VideoInfo
        exclude = ['user',]
```